# Converting a docx containing a chart to PDF

Tags: java, pdf, charts, docx, docx4j

I've got a docx4j generated file which contains several tables, titles and, finally, an excel-generated curve chart.

I have tried many approaches in order to convert this file to PDF, but did not get to any successful result.

1. Docx4j with xsl-fo did not work, most of the things included in the docx file are not yet implemented and show up in red text as "not implemented".
2. JODConverter did not work either, I got a resulting PDF in which everything was pretty good (just little formatting/styling issues) BUT the graph did not show up.
3. Finally, the closest approach was using Apache POI: The resulting PDF was identical to my docx file, but still no chart showing up.
4. I already know Aspose would solve this pretty easily, but I am looking for an open source, free solution.

The code I am using with Apache POI is as follows:

```
public static void convert(String inputPath, String outputPath)
        throws XWPFConverterException, IOException {
    PdfConverter converter = new PdfConverter();
    converter.convert(new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File(
            inputPath))), new FileOutputStream(new File(outputPath)),
            PdfOptions.create());
}
```

I do not know what to do to get the chart inside the PDF, could anybody tell me how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this helps you but you could use "jacob" (I don't know if its possible with apache poi or docx4j)
With this solution you open "Word" yourself and export it as pdf.

!**Word needs to be installed on the computer**!

Heres the download-page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/

```
try {           
        if (System.getProperty("os.arch").contains("64")) {
            System.load(DLL_64BIT_PATH);
        } else {
            System.load(DLL_32BIT_PATH);
        }
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        //TODO          
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO          
    }

 ActiveXComponent oleComponent = new ActiveXComponent("Word.Application");
 oleComponent.setProperty("Visible", false);
 Variant var = Dispatch.get(oleComponent, "Documents");
 Dispatch document = var.getDispatch();

 Dispatch activeDoc = Dispatch.call(document, "Open", fileName).toDispatch();

// https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff845579.aspx
Dispatch.call(activeDoc, "ExportAsFixedFormat", new Object[] { "path to pdfFile.pdf", new Integer(17), false, 0 });
Object args[] = { new Integer(0) };//private static final int DO_NOT_SAVE_CHANGES = 0;
Dispatch.call(activeDoc, "Close", args); 
Dispatch.call(oleComponent, "Quit");
```

Comment: Wow mate, this was awesome. Thanks a million, I've been struggling myself for ages with this, and that was an insta-solve!

Comment: @Keews glad to hear it helped. (I've gone through the same). I ended up doing all my Word creation/editing-stuff with jacob. There is hardly any documentation, but if you search through the net/microsoft help pages you can do nearly anything ...

Comment: definitely this is THE tool I was looking for :) Thank you!